# Error setting a text field, setValue is not a function. Extjs6

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

The function to set the value of the text field. The error setValue is not a function

There are two main components in my application:`Ext.tree.Panel и Ext.form.Panel`
When I click on a tree record, it is necessary that the form fields are filled with the values ​​of the selected record.
To do this in the controller - ListViewController.js in the showDataFields function, I do this:

```
var name_field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#name_field')
var code_field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#code_field')
name_field.setValue(selectedItem.data.text)
```

I get an error in the console:

> TypeError: name_field.setValue is not a function

How to set field values ​​correctly in my case?

For clarity, created the application in **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mg8)**

Comment: Your fiddle is not working

Comment: try this `name_field[0].setValue(selectedItem.data.text)` because `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` will always return an array.

Comment: Yes you're right